# Using Crispy Forms with django, error template does not exist at uni_form/uni_form.html

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have ran `python3.9 -m pip install django-crispy-forms`

Then added the following to settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   # default apps excluded
    'crispy_forms',
    'core.apps.CoreConfig',
]
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'uni_form'
```

Then am attempting to use the crispy filter in a template:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        {{form|crispy}}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and am getting a

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /uni_form/uni_form.html
```

error.

I am not really what is going on? I see that if you wanted to use the bootstrap version you have to download another package such as django-crispy-forms-bootstrap4 but I am just trying to use the default version, so I think I installed the only necessary package.  I've definitely used cripsy forms in a django project before so am not sure what I am forgetting. Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uni-form template pack was removed in django-crispy-forms 2.0.

You can still use the uni-form template pack by installing the latest version from the 1.x series with `pip install "django-crispy-forms<2.0"`.